# How to install yum repository key with ansible?

Tags: centos, ansible, passenger, yum, gnupg

I tried it [two ways](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/el7/):

```
- name: Add repository
  yum_repository:
    # from https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/yum/definitions/el-passenger.repo
    name: passenger
    description: Passenger repository
    baseurl: https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/yum/passenger/el/$releasever/$basearch
    repo_gpgcheck: 1
    gpgcheck: 0
    enabled: 1
    gpgkey: https://packagecloud.io/gpg.key
    sslverify: 1
    sslcacert: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt

- name: Add repository key (option 1)
  rpm_key:
    key: https://packagecloud.io/gpg.key

- name: Add repository key (option 2)
  command: rpm --import https://packagecloud.io/gpg.key

- name: Install nginx with passenger
  yum: name={{ item }}
  with_items: [nginx, passenger]
```

But for it to work, I need to ssh to the machine, confirm importing the key (by running any `yum` command, e.g. `yum list installed`), and then continue provisioning. Is there a way to do it automatically?

**UPD** here's what `ansible` says:

```
TASK [nginx : Add repository key] **********************************************
changed: [default]

TASK [nginx : Install nginx with passenger] ************************************
failed: [default] (item=[u'nginx', u'passenger']) => {"failed": true, "item": ["nginx", "passenger"], "msg": "Failure talking
 to yum: failure: repodata/repomd.xml from passenger: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.\nhttps://oss-binaries.phusionpassen
ger.com/yum/passenger/el/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml signature could not be verified for passenger"}
```

So, the key is indeed imported in both cases, but to be used it must be confirmed.

Comment: you should be able to use the `expect` module instead of the command one to automate user interaction

Comment: Did you get an error with the `rpm_key` module? Or why did you try to add the key with `command` module?

Comment: @knowhy I added more details to my question. But to answer yours, no, no error. It's just that it's not enough for packages to be installed. See `ansible` output above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by running `yum` directly with `-y` switch (and using `rpm_key` module, if anything):

```
- name: Install nginx with passenger
  command: yum -y install {{ item }}
  with_items: [nginx, passenger]
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding the repository and the repository key, just update that repo's metadata with:

```
- name: update repo cache for the new repo
  command: yum -q makecache -y --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=passenger
```

Then proceed with `yum: name=...` as before.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, but unfortunately it [didn't](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/5f177639dea7295a7192b87c0e43812a) work out. Also, it'd be a good thing to make it not run every time. To not let it look like provisioning changed something, when in reality it doesn't. Since `command` tasks are marked changed by default. Also, `-q` switch is not needed here. But that's no big deal, surely.

Comment: I came across the [yumrepo Ansible role](https://github.com/picotrading/ansible-yumrepo) that looks like it has handling for repo keys, so it may be something to try out. I also opened a report in [Ansible's issue tracker](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/20711), as it really should be handled properly by the `rpm_key` module.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I forgot that it needs EPEL repository as well. With [this playbook](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/9f3902d9f7784377315ccf5f2fce328b) it succeeds. Consider add it or link to it to your answer, please.

Comment: On second thought, I think `yum makecache` doesn't convey the intention, so `yum -y install` seems like a better option.